# Ruby on Rails: Adding Additional RESTFUL Actions

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rest, routes, crud

In my rails app I would like to have two patch methods for updating the users profile.

First, I will have an 'account_settings' GET request, which will use the standard edit/update REST action to update certain parameters. Then, I would like to have an additional 'edit_profile' and 'update_profile' actions to get a page that will allow the user to update different user attributes. Here's how it looks in my `users_controller.rb` for a better idea:

```
#For account settings page

    #This is for the account settings page 
    #(only changing email and password)
    def edit
        @user = User.find(params[:id])
    end

    def update
        @user = User.find(params[:id])
        respond_to do |format|
            if @user.update_attributes(account_settings_params)
                flash.now[:success] = "Your settings have been successfully updated."
                format.html {redirect_to @user}
            else
                format.html {redirect_to edit_user_path}
                flash[:error] = "Please be sure to fill out your email, password, and password confirmation."
            end
        end
    end

    def edit_profile
        @user = User.find(params[:id])
    end

    #For update profile
    def update_profile
        @user = User.find(params[:id])
        respond_to do |format|
            if @user.update_attributes(user_profile_params)
                flash.now[:success] = "Your profile has been updated."
                format.html {redirect_to @user}
            else
                format.html {redirect_to edit_profile_user_path}
                flash[:error] = "Please be sure to fill out all the required profile form fields."
            end
        end
    end


    private

    def account_settings_params
        params.require(:user).permit(:email, :password, :password_confirmation)
    end

    def user_profile_params
        params.require(:user).permit(:name, :about_me, :location, :image_url)
    end
```

Selection from my current routes.rb :

```
#Account Settings Just for Email and Password
get 'account_settings' => 'users#edit'
patch 'settings' => 'users#update'
resources :users do
    member do
        get :edit_profile
        put :update_profile
    end
end
```

Results of rake routes:

```
 edit_profile_user GET    /users/:id/edit_profile(.:format)       users#edit_profile
update_profile_user PATCH  /users/:id/update_profile(.:format)     users#update_profile
              users GET    /users(.:format)                        users#index
                    POST   /users(.:format)                        users#create
           new_user GET    /users/new(.:format)                    users#new
          edit_user GET    /users/:id/edit(.:format)               users#edit
               user GET    /users/:id(.:format)                    users#show
                    PATCH  /users/:id(.:format)                    users#update
                    PUT    /users/:id(.:format)                    users#update
                    DELETE /users/:id(.:format)                    users#destroy
```

My navbar partial:

```
            -if logged_in?
                -# Logged in links
                %li
                    =link_to 'Logout', logout_path, method: :delete
                %li
                    =link_to 'Account Settings',edit_user_path(@current_user)
                %li
                    =link_to 'Edit My Profile', edit_profile_user_path(@current_user)
                %li
                    =link_to 'View My Profile', user_path(@current_user)
                %li
                    =link_to 'Members', users_path
```

On the edit_profile page, my form looks like this:

```
=form_for @user, path: update_profile_user_path(@user) do |f|
```

With my current implementation, visiting the edit_profile page and posting the form will lead back to the regular edit page with my rails server saying that the parameters were unpermitted. However, as you can see in my update_profile method in my controller, the controller method for update_profile accepts `user_profile_params` rather than the `account_settings_params` . Any insight onto why it might be doing this?

Comment: use `member` or `collection` block inside users routes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A few notes:

- You don't need `render "edit_profile"` because that is done by default
- You don't need to overwrite the edit route
- I'd strongly suggest actually having a separate Profile controller, instead of trying to hack it in as extra actions on user.

That being said, the routes look like

```
resources :users do
  member do
    get :edit_profile
    patch :update_profile
  end
end
```

then your link would be to users/1/edit_profile (`link_to "edit", edit_profile_path(@user)`) and the form would be to `<%= form_for @user, path: update_user_path(@user) %>`

Comment: Hey, how exactly does it know that the edit profile will take in the user's id as an argument to bring me that path?

Comment: Upated my original post with current routes and error with links

Comment: `rake routes` will give you a list of the routes..! it's probably edit_profile_user_path(@user)  - and as another member here said, the user's id is because it's in the 'member' block.

Comment: however, if i was looking over a job applicant's sample code and they had this vs a separate controller with edit/update for profile I'd go with the latter. much cleaner and more professional.

Comment: Yeah that's true. Tbh I think I'll probably do that, but I think it's also good to know how to do the custom REST actions :)

Comment: For some reason it's still not posting to the proper method. I updated my OP if you'd like to take a look.

Answer (score 1):

To add RESTful routes to the current resources you can use collection or members based on the requirement.
`collection` is used as a non membered resources like index action which gives a collection of objects where as show action needs an object to show. Hence `member` is used to get the action of a single object.
Here you can use

```
resources users do
  resources member do
    get :edit_profile
    put :update_profile
  end
end
```

You can also use

```
resources :users do
  get :edit_profile, on: :member
  put :update_profile, on: :member
end
```